# Getting Coordinates from Another HTML Element for GMAP

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So far I have been trying to implement a simulation for aircraft trip on GMaps.But I encountered an error or a logic (whatever you call) that I couldn't figure out.

In my project briefly I made an database connection to get Runway coordinates then I recieved succesfully and got them to write in labels after then I tried to reach labels through javascript to get coordinates again to enter GMaps but It didn't work.(Map is not opening)
I would be very pleasent,If you could help me.

Thanks in Advance

```
<script>
    var latstrt = 0;
    var longtstrt = 0;
    function Load()
    {
        latstrt = document.getElementById("<%=Label6.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
        longstrt = document.getElementById("<%=Label7.ClientID %>").innerHTML;

        window.alert(latstrt);
    }


    window.onload = function () {
        Load();
        initialize();
    };


window.alert(latstrt);
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latstrt,longtstrt); 
    var elaziz = new google.maps.LatLng(38.608334, 39.291668);
    function initialize() {

        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };



        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myCenter,
            draggable: true,
        });
        var myTrip = [myCenter,elaziz];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: myTrip,
            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        flightPath.setMap(map);


    }




   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

Comment: What output do you get from your alerts? Are there any errors reported in the javascript console?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue and a clear and complete problem statement.

Comment: You only define latstrt and longstrt  in your Load function, but you try and use them here, before that function will probably have executed: `var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latstrt,longtstrt);` Move that line (and the next one with `var elaziz...` inside your `initialize` function.

Comment: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Y);` - what is "Y"?

Comment: Problem here I have encountered is that when I try to read from labels map doesn't appear but instead of reading when I enter numeric values as coordinates The region is shown on the map

Comment: Most probably it is emerged from execution sequence but I couldn't figure out how to cope with it

Comment: At first alert I recieved 0 and at second one I recieved the actual coordinate "39,291668"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code which should work:

```js
function initialize() {
    var latstrt = document.getElementById("<%=Label6.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
    var longstrt = document.getElementById("<%=Label7.ClientID %>").innerHTML;

    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latstrt,longtstrt); 
    var elaziz = new google.maps.LatLng(38.608334, 39.291668);

    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        draggable: true,
        map: map
    });
    var myTrip = [myCenter,elaziz];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: myTrip,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        map: map
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work Map doesn't appear at all but thanks for everything anyway